# Curl not accepting a parameter which contains hypen

Tags: curl

I am trying to run a curl with the following url:

```
curl "http://localhost/bank?param=value&key=971f9d8a-b208-48a5-ab37-ae6dcfbf87d7"
```

But the problem is `curl` is not sending the parameter and from server side I am not able to get the both parameter.

But if I try with these cases:

```
curl "http://localhost/bank?param=value"
```

this one

```
curl "http://localhost/bank?param=value&key=971f9d8a"
```

It works perfectly. I also tried like this:

```
curl "http://localhost/bank?param=value&key=\"971f9d8a-b208-48a5-ab37-ae6dcfbf87d7\""
```

It works fine, I am able to get both parameters on server side, the issue is it also sends the quote ie I am getting value of key as "971f9d8a-b208-48a5-ab37-ae6dcfbf87d7" instead of just 971f9d8a-b208-48a5-ab37-ae6dcfbf87d7.

I searched lot,but couldn't get useful info. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Have you tested using `-G` and `-d` flags. They might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with -d flas, but let me again try.

Comment: @evading, I tried but still it's not working, here is my attempt: `curl "http://localhost/bank" -d "params={"param0":"ranveer"}&key=971f9d8a-b208-48a5-ab37-ae6dcfbf87d7"`

Comment: I'd try `curl -G --data "param=value&key=971f9d8a-b208-48a5-ab37-ae6dcfbf87d7" http://localhost/bank`

Answer (score 0):

From the comments

I'd try `curl -G --data "param=value&key=971f9d8a-b208-48a5-ab37-ae6dcfbf87d7" http://localhost/bank`